# How to create multiple layer images using Raphael canvas library?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, raphael

Does anyone know how to make multiple drawing layers using Raphael? Here's an example that uses a plain canvas object:

http://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same method as they used with canvas.

Create div elements in the html code, give each a distinct id.
You can initialize Raphael on an existing element by using `paper=new Raphael('elementId',width,height)`.

This makes is possible to apply css rules to the elements.
Set the css just like in [the article](http://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers/):

Apply `position: absolute;` to all elements and use `z-index` to stack the elements in the order you want.

[CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)